# Only copy first child element to output

Tags: xslt

My source xml has different nodes with the same tag name. I want to transform this xml into a xml where each child node is unique e.g. this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<shiporder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" orderid="orderid1">
  <orderperson>orderperson1</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>name1</name>
    <address>address1</address>
    <city>city1</city>
    <country>country1</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>title1</title>
    <note>note1</note>
    <note>1</note>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>title2</title>
    <note>note2</note>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

The result after my transformation should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<shiporder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" orderid="orderid1">
  <orderperson>orderperson1</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>name1</name>
    <address>address1</address>
    <city>city1</city>
    <country>country1</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>title1</title>
    <note>note1</note>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

I tried to select the first child via `*[1]` if there are more then once with same tag name but till now I dont get the right result:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0 you could try

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="name" match="*" use="node-name(.)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(. is key('name', node-name(.), ..)[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which should do for the sample you have shown. On the other hand, if elements of the same name can be nested a different pattern is necessary:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.) eq node-name(current())]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thx for the exception of nested pattern.  Could you please add some explanations for the cycle of the pattern which is defined by `*[preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.) eq node-name(current())]]`?

Comment: The pattern `*[preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.) eq node-name(current())]]` matches any element that has a preceding sibling element of the same qualified name, i.e. that has a preceding sibling element of the same local name in the same namespace.

Comment: But then I dont understand why it does not copy all the other notes of name "item" which has a preceding sibling?

Comment: The template `<xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.) eq node-name(current())]]"/>` is empty, meaning any matching element is not processed further, together with the other template that means that elements that have preceding sibling of the same QName are not copied.